# How to determine layout for cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

In asp.net MVC, when I'm working in a cshtml file, is there a way to determine the parent layout file if I don't know which one it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default layout page is defined in `/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

otherwise it is specified in the `.cshtml` file at the top

Comment: What happens if there isn't a Layout referenced in the cshtml file?

Comment: It will use the Default that is referenced in the _ViewStart.cshtml